# Очень медленно работает UPDATE

Tags: update, mysql

Столкнулся в первый раз с таким. У клиента на сервере очень медленно обновляется запись в бд.

```
UPDATE `cms_product` SET `product_viewed` = `product_viewed`+1 WHERE `product_id` =  '9' LIMIT 1
```

эта команда выполняется иногда до 6 секунд. Что самое смешное, что в таблице 4 записи.
Выборка c JOIN работает быстро с  (0.0001).
И даже :
UPDATE `cms_product` SET `product_viewed` = '1' WHERE `product_id` =  '9' LIMIT 1 // took me 3.8 seconds

Comment: у вас наверное лишний индекс, например на product_viewed

Comment: С четырьмя записями я думаю даже 100 индексов не почувстуешь

Comment: а, пропустил, ну тогда может триггер какой ?

Comment: Я не писал триггеров. 

Индексы:
PRIMARY product_id
roduct_cat_id
product_url.

Что еще есть, так это связь с другой таблицей. Но там тоже пару записей. Т.е. сайт залился только на сервер. На локалке и на другом серваке летал

Comment: Могут ли из-за связей таблиц быть такие глюки?

Comment: [посмотрите сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316122/mysql-very-slow-update-insert-delete-queries-hanging-on-query-end-step), там в вопросе хороший способ диагностики. попробуйте залить дамп ещё куда-нибудь,  посмотрите  dmesg на сервере (может у вас проблемы с железом), посмотрите логи mysql и системные логи, сделайте mysqlcheck

Comment: если всё работает на другом сервере, то проблема либо в самом хостинге, либо в настройках mysqld, ну ещё вариант - там какая-нибудь бажная версия mysql стоит.

---
@Victor Halauko без диагностики никак не решить.

Comment: это мой ноут и сервер (из переписки с клиентом)
http://clip2net.com/clip/m255804/1392671782-clip-19kb.png?nocache=1
http://clip2net.com/clip/m255804/1392671854-clip-26kb.png?nocache=1

Comment: А систему хранения данных сравнивали? MyISAM не особенно-то любит апдейты.

Comment: блокирует. сделайте unlock

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте:

оптимизировать запросы/таблицы

использовать PostgreSQL

воспользоватся другим хостом или hardware'ом

Comment: Просто взять и сменить MySQL на PostgreSQL только потому, что один запрос медленно работает - очень, очень плохой совет.

Comment: Я же не сказал немедленно менять БД. Я просто предположил то, что можно сделать.